# Why isn't Photomatix working with RAW bracketed photos?

Tags: raw, hdr

HELP!! Lately, Photomatix will only process a few out of many RAW bracketed interior photos from my real estate shoots. Why is this, and what can I do to fix this problem?

I use a Nikon D5300 and have it set for auto bracketing, 3 photos. I love RAW, vs. JPEG results, but Photomatix isn't processing many of the RAWs. It did on a couple shoots, but this last shoot it only processed 10 or so photos. I get a batch failed error message for most of the shots:

`## Error: Batch failed with code: -1073741819`

Comment: Please update your question with version of Photomatix, wersion of operating system. Did you try to convert photos to TIFF and try again?